# How to add constructors to a list, and call them in a different class

Tags: c#

We need to make an application for a fictional company that sells mp3 players in school. I have the login code, menu code, I can display all products but now it's getting a bit tricky.

I've made a constructor to add all the players and data **in a different class**:

```
public Mp3players(int id, string make, string model, int mbsize, double price, int stock)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.mbsize = mbsize;
    this.price = price;
    this.stock = stock;
}
```

But all the players need to go in the same class, and need to be **accessible in the program class** like so:

```
public static void ShowMenu()
{
    Console.WriteLine(
      "Beschikbare menu keuzes: \n 1: MP3 spelers \n 2: Overzicht voorraad \n 3: \n 4: \n 5: \n 6: \n 7: \n 8: \n 9: Afsluiten"); //selectie menu

    bool keuze = false;

    while (keuze == false)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo selectie = Console.ReadKey(true);

        switch (selectie.KeyChar)
        {
            case '1':
                foreach (Mp3players speler in Mp3players.player) //print alle mp3spelers in de list
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}", speler.id);
                    Console.WriteLine("Make: {0}", speler.make);
                    Console.WriteLine("Model: {0}", speler.model);
                    Console.WriteLine("MB Size: {0}", speler.mbsize);
                    Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", speler.price + "\n");
                }

                break;
            case '2':
                Stock();
                break;
```

What i'm trying to achieve works if i make new mp3 players in the same method, but that is a bit inappropriate since i need to access the mp3 players list in multiple methods.

I know this is a bit messy, i'm completely new to asking these complex questions. Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at collections e.g. a List and add a method that returns a List of MP3Players or an IEnumerable would be better

Comment: Thank you very much for reading and actually answering. To be honest with you, i don't know how to use an IEnumerable or collections, so i just kept using my list. 

What i did was making a method in the seperate class that returned the list. And in the program.cs i just called that method when i needed the data in that list.